# Loop to convert different columns in data frames from list

Tags: r, list, dataframe, apply, lapply

I would like to have a loop over a list of data frames that converts specific columns from data frames as numeric(in my case its's second and third column of each data frame within the list)
  I already have some code here and don't know why it isn't working...

Could some1 help me ?

```
lapply(myfiles2[[]][[,c(2,3)]], as.numeric)
```

Comment: [Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) example please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not so hard. Yoy have to loop (`lapply`) through the list changing each member data.frame's columns of interest with another call to `lapply`.

First, some example dataset, since you have posted none.

```
set.seed(1234)
myfiles2 <- lapply(1:4, function(i){
  data.frame(X = letters[1:5], Y = factor(sample(5)), Z = as.character(11:15))
})

str(myfiles2)    # output omited
```

Now, the problem.

```
cols <- 2:3
myfiles3 <- lapply(myfiles2, function(DF){
  DF[cols] <- lapply(DF[cols], as.numeric)
  DF
})
```

To see that it worked any of the following two will do.

```
lapply(myfiles3, function(DF) sapply(DF, class))

str(myfiles3)
#List of 4
# $ :'data.frame':  5 obs. of  3 variables:
#  ..$ X: Factor w/ 5 levels "a","b","c","d",..: 1 2 3 4 5
#  ..$ Y: num [1:5] 1 3 2 4 5
#  ..$ Z: num [1:5] 1 2 3 4 5
# $ :'data.frame':  5 obs. of  3 variables:
#  ..$ X: Factor w/ 5 levels "a","b","c","d",..: 1 2 3 4 5
#  ..$ Y: num [1:5] 4 1 5 2 3
#  ..$ Z: num [1:5] 1 2 3 4 5
# $ :'data.frame':  5 obs. of  3 variables:
#  ..$ X: Factor w/ 5 levels "a","b","c","d",..: 1 2 3 4 5
#  ..$ Y: num [1:5] 4 3 1 2 5
#  ..$ Z: num [1:5] 1 2 3 4 5
# $ :'data.frame':  5 obs. of  3 variables:
#  ..$ X: Factor w/ 5 levels "a","b","c","d",..: 1 2 3 4 5
#  ..$ Y: num [1:5] 5 2 1 3 4
#  ..$ Z: num [1:5] 1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: Thank you so much. You're right, it was so simple, had thought about looping within each element of list and but I only made up something with (`for`) loops